# Symfony - Get a container inside an Interface

Tags: php, symfony, shopware

I'm using symfony and need to know how to inject a container into the EventSubscriberInterface?

My goal it to use the "mail_template_type.repository". It works fine in a controller but the EventSubscriberInterface seems no to have a container or at least dumpe($event) does not show it.

```
         /**
         * @var EntityRepositoryInterface $mailTypeRepository
         * @var EntityRepositoryInterface $mailRepository
         */
        $mailTypeRepository = getContainer()->get('mail_template_type.repository');
        $mailRepository = getContainer()->get('mail_template.repository');
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
namespace RegistrationExtension\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEvents;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEntity;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Event\CustomerRegisterEvent;
use Shopware\Storefront\Page\Account\Login\AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

use RegisterExtension\Struct\RegisterStruct;


class RegisterExtensionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface|NULL $container
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = NULL){
        $this->container = $container;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return ContainerInterface
     */
    protected function getContainer(){
        return $this->container;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array{
        return [
            AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onCustomRegister'
        ];
    }
    public function onCustomRegister(AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent $event){
        //dump($this->getContainer('mail_template_type.repository'));
        //$event->getPage()->addExtension('custom_struct', new RegisterStruct());
         /**
         * @var EntityRepositoryInterface $mailTypeRepository
         * @var EntityRepositoryInterface $mailRepository
         */
        $mailTypeRepository = getContainer()->get('mail_template_type.repository');
        $mailRepository = getContainer()->get('mail_template.repository');
        
        $mailEntity = $mailTypeRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template_type.technicalName', "customer_register")),
            $event->getContext()
        );

        $mailTypeId = $mailEntity->getEntities()->first()->getId();


        $mailEntity = $mailRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template.mailTemplateTypeId', $mailTypeId)),
            $event->getContext()
        );
        
        //$mailEntity->getEntities()->setContentHtml("test");
        $mail = $mailEntity->getEntities();
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="RegistrationExtension\Storefront\Controller\RegistrationExtensionController" public="true"> </service>
        <service id="RegistrationExtension\Subscriber\RegisterExtensionSubscriber">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Comment: You could create a service to inject it. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: Please post your config that enables the `RegisterExtensionSubscriber`. Generally you should avoid accessing the container directly. Instead use dependency injection and/or autowire to inject the services you need into the service. Alternatively you can use `implements EventSubscriberInterface, ContainerAwareInterface`, but as I said this is [highly discouraged](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#services-should-be-private-whenever-possible) by the Symfony developers.

Comment: Well i guess i will try the service injection aproach. Not really sure how to do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you should utilize dependency injection to add only the services you need instead of the entire container.

Be sure to clear and warmup your Symfony cache after making the changes below.

### autowire services

In Symfony 3.4+ you can utilize `autowire`, which will automatically inject known FQCN services into the `__construct` for example using the logger service.

*vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Resources/config/monolog.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="monolog.logger" parent="monolog.logger_prototype" public="false">
            <argument index="0">app</argument>
            <call method="useMicrosecondTimestamps">
                <argument>%monolog.use_microseconds%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
        <service id="logger" alias="monolog.logger" />

        <service id="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" alias="logger" public="false" />

        <!-- ... -->

        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

*config/services.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <!-- attempts to inject and tag services automatically -->
        <defaults autowire="true" autoconfigure="true" public="false"/>

        <service id="RegistrationExtension\Storefront\Controller\RegistrationExtensionController" public="true"> </service>
        <service id="RegistrationExtension\Subscriber\RegisterExtensionSubscriber">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

*src/RegistrationExtension/Subscriber/RegisterExtensionSubscriber.php*

```php
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class RegisterExtensionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface 
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) 
    {
         $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

### Dependency Injection

If the service can not use `autowire` to be injected because it uses a string service name instead of FQCN you can manually declare the service in your config.

*config/services.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>

        <service id="RegistrationExtension\Storefront\Controller\RegistrationExtensionController" public="true"> </service>
        <service id="RegistrationExtension\Subscriber\RegisterExtensionSubscriber">
            <argument type="service" id="mail_template_type.repository" />
            <argument type="service" id="mail_template.repository" />
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

*src/RegistrationExtension/Subscriber/RegisterExtensionSubscriber.php*

```php
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
//...

class RegisterExtensionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface 
{

    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $mailTypeRepository;

    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $mailRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepositoryInterface $mailTypeRepository,
        EntityRepositoryInterface $mailRepository
    ) {
         $this->mailTypeRepository = $mailTypeRepository;
         $this->mailRepository = $mailRepository;
    }

    public function onCustomRegister(AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent $event)
    {        
        $mailEntity = $this->mailTypeRepository->search(
            (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template_type.technicalName', "customer_register")),
            $event->getContext()
        );

        if ($mailType = $mailEntity->getEntities()->first()) {
            $mailEntity = $this->mailRepository->search(
                (new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('mail_template.mailTemplateTypeId', $mailType->getId())),
                $event->getContext()
            );
        
            $mail = $mailEntity->getEntities();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```